# How to set HTTP client hints in Django web app?

Tags: django, http-headers

I would like to set [HTTP client hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Client_hints) in a Django web app. I am especially interested in `Sec-CH-Prefers-Color-Scheme`, which is supported in Chromium browsers to detect the preferred color theme server side. It seems I have to send the browser the hint somehow so that it includes it in the request headers.

Comment: you probably want to use custom middleware to set the HTTP Header like method 2 at https://idiomaticprogrammers.com/post/custom-response-header-in-django/